# How to minimize the total delivered price when buying many items from many different sources

Tags: mathematical-optimization

In the past, I have often had a problem that I have tried to solve with a large matrix in Excel. Now I want to solve the problem in Mathematica because the matrix is getting larger and the problem more complex. In the matrix there are prices for different items (rows) and different shops (columns). There is one special row for the delivery costs of each shop and one special column for the amount of each item.

I want to find out which shop is best for buying each item. Of course, I want to save as much money as possible. It is not as simple as just picking the shops where the items are the cheapest because the delivery costs may destroy the "item-price-advantage".

At first I would create two vectors and two matrices:

```
deliveryCosts = {dcShopA, dcShopB, ... };
amount = {aItem1, aItem2, ... };
singleprices = 
  {{priceItem1ShopA, priceItem1ShopB, ... }, 
   {priceItem2ShopA, priceItem2ShopB, ... }, ...};
amountprices = singleprices*amount;
```

So some sample data may be:

```
singlePrices = {{5.53, 5.54, 5.68, 6.03, 6.82, 6.43, 6.98}, {2.69, 
    2.58, 2.74, 2.93, 2.58, 3.22, 2.58}, {1.09, 1.11, 1.18, 1.26, 
    1.11, 1.39, 1.13}, {2.69, 2.8, 2.9, 3.02, 2.74, 3.24, 2.75}, {3.2,
     3.84, 3.99, 4.14, 3.76, 4.44, 3.78}, {6, 7.01, 7.27, 7.01, 6.88, 
    8.1, 7.15}, {11.25, 11.32, 11.75, 12.22, 11.12, 13.08, 
    11.59}, {17.16, 17.27, 17.91, 18.64, 99, 19.94, 20.51}, {1.77, 
    1.78, 1.84, 1.92, 1.79, 2.06, 1.81}, {2.41, 2.42, 2.51, 2.61, 
    3.07, 2.8, 2.49}, {4.39, 4.42, 4.58, 4.77, 5.6, 5.11, 
    4.55}, {3.88, 3.95, 4.09, 4.26, 3.86, 4.56, 3.85}, {11.94, 11.66, 
    12.09, 12.58, 11.9, 13.47, 10.44}, {16.07, 15.73, 16.31, 16.98, 
    14.9, 18.17, 15.35}, {1.17, 1.19, 1.24, 1.29, 1.51, 1.38, 
    1.41}, {14.24, 13.9, 14.42, 15.01, 17.65, 16.07, 13.77}, {22.64, 
    22.13, 22.94, 23.9, 28.08, 25.56, 26.28}, {9.98, 9.8, 10.16, 
    10.58, 9.95, 11.33, 10.1}, {16.27, 16.37, 16.98, 17.67, 20.78, 
    18.92, 19.45}, {10.84, 10.61, 11.01, 11.46, 13.47, 12.26, 
    12.61}, {35.39, 35.4, 36.71, 38.21, 44.92, 40.9, 42.05}};
amounts = {1, 24, 5, 46, 16, 6, 5, 2, 10, 1, 1, 76, 2, 8, 20, 4, 1, 8,
    2, 3, 2};
derliveryCosts = {0, 4.95, 5.9, 5.9, 6.9, 4.9, 6.9, 7.99};
```

Now I have my input values. But how do I proceed best-practice-like?

Comment: This is not a site for Excel questions.

Comment: thanks for comment, I edited my post. It has not been clear, that I want to solve the problem with mathematica now...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also add sample data, making that up would be a hassle.

Comment: Look up `LinearPrograming` in documentation.

Comment: Also, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html can be of help. Do I remember right that `Minimize` could effectively perform integer linear programming efficiently for problems stated in a nice form?

Comment: LinearPrograming sounds like the right functionality for this problem. But I don't know how to get started...

Comment: Can you at least formulate this as an LP problem?

Comment: My idea without linearprogramming was to generate matrices with entries 1 and 0. 1 means buy article from this row in the shop from this column. the rest of the row is filled with 0. I wanted to build some for loops to create every possible combination and pick the combination with the lowest total costs. I'm not familiar with linearprogramming so I have to read the documentation and test some things with it to be able to formulate it as an lp problem.

Comment: just added some sample data

Comment: derliverycosts (sic) has a length of `8`, while singlePrices has dimensions `{21,7}`

Comment: Could you write in latex your problem it will be easier to think of it

Comment: I was not even thinking about *Mathematica* when I asked you; I was asking if you are familiar with *mathematically* formulating an LP problem, with the constraints and everything. Can you at least look in a textbook on LP (of which there are a number of excellent ones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really checked if this produces sensible results.

```
Module[{shops, products, singlePrices, deliveryCosts, amount},
   shops = 5;
   products = 10;
   (* Bogus data. *)
   singlePrices = 
    Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[n, 1/5], shops], {n, products}];
   deliveryCosts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1], shops];
   amount = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, products];
   LinearProgramming[
     (* Minimize sum of prices times amounts (including delivery costs). *)
     Join[Flatten@singlePrices, deliveryCosts],
     Join[
      (* Sum of per-product amounts over all shops. *)
      Table[Join[
        Flatten@Table[Boole[i == n], {n, products}, {m, shops}], 
        ConstantArray[0, shops]], {i, products}] ,
      (* This forces amount of deliveries to be at least one if sum of products ordered from that shop is non-zero. *)
      Table[Join[
        Flatten@Table[Boole[i == m], {n, products}, {m, shops}], 
        Table[-Total@amount Boole[i == ii], {ii, shops}]], {i, shops}]],
     Join[
      (* Force amounts over all shops to be exact. *)
      {#, 0} & /@ amount,
      (* Force shipping cost constraint to hold. *)
      {0, -1} & /@ deliveryCosts],
     (* Perform integer linear programming. *)
     Automatic, 
     Integers] // Partition[#, shops] &] // Transpose // TableForm
```

Example output:

> $$
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 10 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  10 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Each row represents a shop, and every item there is an amount to order for product types, and last one is the "delivery" product.